# Find the integral of $\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {Q\left( {f(\theta )} \right)Q\left( {g(\theta )} \right)d\theta } $?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to find the integral of the following function:

$\int\limits_0^{2\pi } {Q\left( { - (e*\cos (a + \theta )*sqrt(x) + g} \right)*Q\left( { - (f*\sin (a + \theta )*sqrt(x) + h} \right)d\theta } $

Where, $Q\left( x \right) = \frac{1}{{2\pi }}\int\limits_x^\infty  {{e^{ - \frac{{{t^2}}}{2}}}dt} $.

I tried using wolfram Alpha but it did not give me any result. I dont know how to start. Thank you.

Comment: Are we to understand that the trig functions are in the argument of the function Q? I suspect the integral does not have an answer in terms of any elementary functions.

Comment: I was trying to do that but had no idea how to deal with it. Thanks